# websphere: requested url was not found on this server

Tags: jsf, web-deployment, websphere-8

I am developing my first web application with EJB, JSF and JPA. I use rational developer for developement and test, and our server is an iSeries with websphere 8. I do not have access to the test and production server, i can only manage the one I locally installed for developement purpose.

So now, my web application is working perfectly on my local installation, but I can't make it work on the production or test server. I produce the EAR with Rational Developer, our sysadmin publishes it on the server, the logs show no error (everything seems fine), but when I then try to reach the application via browser, i get the message

> 404 not found: requested url was not found on this server

In locale, i have the application installed under

```
http://localhost:9080/<contextroot>/pages/login.jsf
```

I tried several different urls but I always get that error message:

```
http://<production_server_url>/<contextroot>/pages/login.jsf
http://<production_server_url>:80/<contextroot>/pages/login.jsf
http://<production_server_url>:9080/<contextroot>/pages/login.jsf
http://<production_server_url>/<contextroot>/
```

I asked the sysadmin to send me the screenshots of the steps he goes through when installing the app on the server to see if there was some difference in the configuration, but everything is the same. The contextroot is correct.

We have other web applications that run on the servers, but those are simple .war files, this is the first EAR we try to deploy (i.e. as such, websphere incapuslates war files into ear projects in order to run them)

We have no idea what to do, can anyone help?

What bothers me the most is that the deploy itself goes well, the app is installed and running, I just cannot reach it

Thanks

Comment: normally there is something "in front" of a production server (e.g. load balanacer, router, ... in 9x% an "Apache"), and the system admin has to ensure that http://<production_server_url>/[</what/ever/your/entry/point>][:80:443]?is routed to `http://localhost:9080/<contextroot>/whatever/developer/considers/entrypoint` .. is this the 1st time release??

Comment: iSeries sometimes uses a funky set of ports rather than the defaults, so that might be worth looking at.  Check your profile's config/cells/<cellname>/nodes/<nodename>/serverindex.xml, find the serverEntries section for your server, and look for the endpoint named "WC_defaulthost" (or "WC_defaulthost_secure", if you're using security, although your mention of port 9080 above implies that you're not).  That will have a "port" value that would be the right one for your server.

Comment: @xerx593 yes, this is the first release we make for this application

Comment: @Jarid will check, thanks! I just want to stress that I am using port 9080 on my local websphere installation (i.e. on my pc where I write and test code), the production server might well have some kind of security settings

Comment: @Jarid found WC_defaulthost in serverindex.xml and using that port does give some better result! Going to check with a newer version of the application (i went on with developement since last deploy) and see if it works.
I was wondering: i see the ports are different between production server and test server, where can the sysadmin configure some kind of routing in order to avoid the use of explicitly stating the ports in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The application server was running on a different, non-standard port. As suggested by @Jarid i found the correct port under

```
<profile_config>/cells/<cellname>/nodes/<nodename>/serverindex.xml
```

at endpoint `WC_defaulthost`. I can access the application at

```
http://<production_server_url>:>WC_defaulthost_port>/<contextroot>/pages/login.jsf
```